# ssh -T git@gitlab.com git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: gitlab

I can clone from gitlab, but the login will report an error

```
git clone ssh is success
```

but

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: explain it more clearly or put some information for context what you are doing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Gitlab CI is not allowing you to enter a keyboard-interactive terminal within a Job. Indeed, there would be no keyboard attached to this machine because it is on a remote server.

I think you should specify which command you want to run, like `ssh sample.ssh.com  ls /tmp/doc`